# Thread safety of Servlet Request/InputStream and Response/OutputStream as per Servlet Spec

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I was going through the [Thread safety section of Servlet Specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-3.1/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf). It says

> Be aware that other than the startAsync, and complete methods, the
> request and response objects are not thread safe. If those objects
> were accessed in the multiple threads, the access should be
> synchronized or be done through a wrapper to add the thread safety,
> for instance, synchronizing the call of the methods to access the
> request attribute, or using a local output stream for the response
> object within a thread.

My understanding is if there are multiple application threads are trying to access inputstream/request object we need to ensure access to these objects is thread-safe and similarly if the multiple threads are trying to access outputstream/response object ensure thread-safety.

Let us say if we have single thread trying to access request/inputstream and other single thread trying to access response/outputstream independently, do we still need to ensure thread-safety between these threads?

I believe we can have one thread handle servletinputstream and other thread handle servletoutputstream and both can be completely independent and are thread safe.

For ex: Client is sending chunked HTTP request data (blocking read using ServletInputStream) and server is sending chunked HTTP response data (blocking write via ServletOutputStream) and both of them can work independently and concurrently with out any need for synchronization. Would that be fair as per the above specification? Or does that violate the spec?

Please note that, this question is with respect blocking thread model of servlet while reading the inputstream and data is written to outputstream whenever data is available based on backend business logic and not using startAsync although the underlying web container could like non-blocking/async like Undertow or Jetty.

Also, what does it mean by `using a local output stream for the response object within a thread` in the above specification?

Comment: It's really a moot point, because HTTP is a stateless request/response protocol and you shouldn't start to send a response until you're done reading the request. If you want to keep them both streaming in chunk mode, forget that idea, and use **Web Sockets** instead. It's a full-duplex communication channels, invented for just such purpose.

Comment: @Andreas Agree with the Web sockets approach. But this app has been deployed in the field where clients & servers communicate using chunked encoding and so moving to web sockets may not be easy or feasible at this point. Regarding `you shouldn't start to send a response until you're done reading the request` - I agree it is true for a single fire-and-forget approach and for bidirectional communication we can use chunked encoding and keep request & response going simultaneously. Or do you see any HTTP protocol/spec violation here? If so, can point me the relevant spec, that would really help?